# MEF loading failing due to SDK mismatch

Tags: c#, mef

I have a tricky little problem I'm trying to solve. I have an internal (to my org) MEF application that loads in extra packages to handle different requests. My org releases an SDK sporadically. To help manage the constant updates, I have my own private NuGet package with the SDK DLLs that I include in my handlers. I just reference that. The problem is that the environments we deploy to don't always have the latest binaries, so my handlers dont load because it's looking for a specific version of the binary (i.e "Could not load in MyBinary.dll because MefApp.1.1.3 could not be found").

For clarity, my problem looks like this:

SDK Package:

- Contains the binaries with the interfaces I need for the MEF app

Handler Project:

- Imports SDK Package
- Implements expected interfaces etc.
- Does stuff

MEF App:

- Attempts to load "Handler Project"

  - Fails dude to the SDK files being different that what is expected

I would think that this is something that can be handled by assembly redirecting, but the problem is I dont know what version would be on each environment.

Lastly, I understand that if there are major breaking changes this WILL fail and there is no way around that. This is purely for the minor updates where there are no breaking changes.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you would want to build from the command line were you have more options than inside Visual Studio.  The command line you can pass into the compiler the version numbers (create a file with the versions) so you don't get the errors.